# How to copy all files that doesn't start with numbers to another directory - Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to know how to copy all files that don't start with numbers and have the extension '.xls' to another directory.

I'm doing it like this:

```
cp -r ~/*.xls ~/excel | grep -l '[^0-9]*.xls'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Globbing patterns do support negation in character sets**, so try:

```
cp -r ~/[!0-9]*.xls ~/excel
```

Note that Bash also supports `^` instead of `!` as the negation symbol, but the latter is more portable (**`!` is the negation symbol [mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13)**).